# How to set date format ( 2018-04-09 10:10:10 ) input in swagger JSON

Tags: java, json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am currently using below swagger spec for above particular date format

```
"requestDt": {
                "title": "requestDt",
                "description": "requestDt",
                "pattern":"[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]",
                "type":"string"
            }
```

it shows in doc page like below

```
"requestDt": "string"
```

The problem was it showing input in documentation file as a string. How i need to convert this into date so it will be displayed sample date in swagger doc page

Comment: [Data types in swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/) mention date are seen as text. There is no date type. Might be simpler to use the description to specify the date format. The regex is correct so that helps... You can also add [examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Try add `format` as described in spec https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

```
"requestDt": {
                "title": "requestDt",
                "description": "requestDt",
                "type":"string",
                "format" : "date-time"
            }
```